# how to paste contents of named range based on active cell contents using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to paste the contents of a Named Range, based on the active cell contents (which is from a data validation dropdown).

The active cell contents is equal to the Named Range name.

There are 40 odd Named Ranges in the sheet, and I want to paste them into a column by selecting a specific cell and calling the macro.

I can create the variable and assign the active cell contents to the variable, but I don't see how to assign the variable to the name of the named range and paste the contents.

I have tried the following code:

```css
Sub PrintRange()
'
' PrintRange Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+L
'
    Dim LO As Variant
    Set LO = ActiveCell
    Application.Goto Reference:="LO"
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Test page").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
 
End Sub
```

Could anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Have you tried anything

Comment: yes sorry I have it on other computer, in a bit of a rush,

Comment: I am copying by eye -

Comment: dim LO As Variant; Set LO = ActiveCell; Application.Goto Reference = "LO"; Selection.Copy; ActiveCell.Offset etc; ActiveSheet.Paste; End Sub

Comment: What do you think. I have tried several data types etc. I am sure it is how I am assigning the LO variable to the Named Range name...

Comment: I can print a named range once i specify the name in the macro. Its when I try to assign the active cell to the name of the Named Range that I start to get problems. Obviously I could use loads of "if" statements but thats messy.

Comment: You can edit your original question and add the code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you :)

```css
Sub linga()
Dim srcRange As Range, destRange As Range
'Replace Num with your named range
Set srcRange = Range("Num")
Set destRange = ActiveCell.Resize(srcRange.Rows.Count, srcRange.Columns.Count)

destRange.Value = srcRange.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a mill, so is "Num" the variable set initially to the active cell?

Comment: Dont mind that question. Ill figure it out later tonight properly. I see what you are getting at. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly at the end of the day:

Sub PrintRange()
'
' PrintRange Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+L
'
    LO = ActiveCell
    Application.Goto Reference:=(LO)
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Data Entry").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub